# How to get Current logged in user in Provider Hosted App?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, user

How can I get Current Logged in user of ***SharePoint Site*** in Provider Hosted App's code behind?
I tried this:

1. ```
   clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    var login_nm = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
   ```
2. `userName = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToString();`
3. `string u_nm = User.Identity.Name.ToString();`

But what I am getting is *current System User*. Not the SharePoint user.
 Above all the Options are to get the Windows User Identity. Not for SharePoint site. What should I do to get SharePoint user in my App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should return the current user: (Works for me here)

```
Web web = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

clientContext.Load(web.CurrentUser);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
currentUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
```

Comment: Above My code is somewhat same as yours. But did you try to create user in **SharePoint**. And not in System User. I mean to say I am getting my System users only. Because my app is running on localhost when I debug it. but how to get SharePoint user in that.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your reply question. That is the SharePoint user who I am connected to and using the app as. Are you elevating anything?

Comment: I am telling you that when I run my I from VS in FireFox browser I need to Login twice. First is for my SharePoint site and other is for my Localhost. So when App is running I am getting the localhost user that is System user. And when I run on IE it always give me the System User from which I am logged in.

Comment: Does your app run on Localhost..? Or SharePoint server..?

Comment: It runs on a separate app server

Comment: Ohk. My app is running on LocalHost... I think this will be the reason that I am getting the local users in my app.

Comment: Do you happen to have the full code above? Thanks. I have a line like this: `var c = new ClientContext(_hostWebUrl);` where `_hostWebUrl` is my SP site. I am receiving the following error: `ServerVersion = 'c.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'`

Comment: If you want other properties, you need to load them in the load method. Only information you ask for will be retrieved.

Comment: Is it possible to do exactly the same thing but in the javascript part ? Or i'll have to get it via .NET C# server-side and serialize the value into javascript.

Comment: Hi @Alex please refer to this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73032/get-current-user-in-client-object-model-with-javascript it is indeed similar but not the same

Comment: @HughWood thanks for the link! I managed to do it by accessing the SP context via my webpart, by calling the parent global scope :  `parent._spPageContextInfo.userId`. This way I can retrieve all the informations from the current session, into my App, accessed by my webpart . ;)

Comment: Sometimes this isn't available because it's populated into the page context, so ensure it is tested to this effect and that your code runs late enough in the page cycle that it will work as intended.