# Add New Property in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, powerapp

In SharePoint Online we need to add a custom Property in Office365 Users and than it will be visible to SharePoint: User Profile Services and in Power-app forms.

[image]

And we will be able to consume that custom property here in our Power-app forms like below:
[image]

Thanks,
-Taha

Answer (score 2):

That form is not connected to the User Profile Service. You can add new properties in the SharePoint Online Admin center under the User Profile Properties - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-user-profiles-in-the-SharePoint-admin-center-494bec9c-6654-41f0-920f-f7f937ea9723#customuserproperties. If you want to use JSOM, you can get the profile property as shown in the answer here: [Get Current Login User Profile Properties SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158591/get-current-login-user-profile-properties-sharepoint).

Comment: If I will add custom property in SP UPS, will not be able to get them in Power-apps. Is this is power-apps limitation or I am doing something wrong? And why we have limitation in Office365 Users Management?