# Fetch User Details in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-designer, jquery, csom

I have a requirement to fetch user details in SharePoint 2010. Just like SharePoint 2013, are there any web services available which can used in JavaScript Code?

I need to fetch user details that include mobile number, organization name, office.

Please suggest the solution for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in SharePoint 2010 by querying following end-point.

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList
```

Add your required properties in `$select` operator.

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList?$select=Id,Name,..
```

## Example using jQuery

```
function getUsers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hey buddy thanks will plss expand your  suggestion .....i am new to sharepoint

Comment: check my example

Comment: thanks budddy let me implement it and i will get back to u.

Comment: The user info list is only a subset of user information from the User Profile. For the full user profile you can hit the User Profile Web Service (/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx) and make a SOAP request. There are 1000s of examples on the web for this.

Comment: guys thanks for help...how to get attributes from that response variable...

Comment: i tried using  response.d.name but not succesfule...debugged the codeand found that respnse.d is undefined.....plss help

Comment: what's the result of `console.log(response);`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by

1. SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser
2. User information list
3. Use of SP.UserProfiles.js

Refer this [link](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation) for SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser

Get user detail from userInforList [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/10/15/retrieve-all-user-in-sharepoint-2010-site-using-javascript-client-object-model/)

With help of UserProfile.JS [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162734/how-to-use-jsom-csom-in-sharepoint-2010-to-get-information-about-the-current-use)